# Can I assume chicken internal temp rises 5 degrees while resting?

Tags: cast-iron, frying-pan, chicken-breast

With steak I've often read you should remove it from heat about 5 degrees before your target internal temp because it will continue to rise about that much as it rests.

Is the same true for chicken? If your target temp is 165, is it okay to remove from heat when the internal temp is a few degrees lower?

Comment: Is there a specific cut or preparation of chicken you are trying to apply this rule to? To me it seems like the effects of resting depends almost entirely on the thickness of the meat: a whole chicken has a lot more thermal mass than tenders or cutlets.

Comment: @BenjaminKuykendall : also, if you cover it to reduce evaporative cooling vs. just leaving it out of the oven, or if it's been moved to a cold plate vs. left in the warm pan.  And maybe what temperature it was cooked at (hot oven 'til removed vs. seared stovetop then left in a moderate oven to cook through)

Comment: Also of note -- this is tagged "cast iron".  And leaving it in a hot cast iron pan is going to continue cooking.

Comment: Frying chicken breast in cast iron. I filet the breasts in half and then beat them so they aren't too thick... which as I think of it may mean the internal temp doesn't raise quite as much while resting as one might expect from a moderately thick cut of steak.

Answer (score 1):

Yes 3C/5F is about right. Chicken is always tricky because you're try to get legs at 72C but breast only at 65C (or even a bit less). Several cooking techniques to achieve that but it's for another post... The thermal mass argument seems to make sense although there is also 'more to do' so I would stick to the general rule of thumb and experiment. Resting is essential (but you already know this) either under foil or in a warm area. If your bird gets a bit too cold, you can flash the cut portions for 2-3 minutes in a hot oven; no need to rest again.